# Hibernate: No results when ran a query to get results between a date range

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, rest

I have used `Hibernate` in my REST API to do the database work. I have basically 3 layers;

1. JSON Service Layer - This will handle the JSON Requests
2. Service Layer - This will handle any operation to the data sent or taken from database layer
3. Database Layer - Works with database. Functions for save, update etc.

Please check the below code

**JSON Service Layer**

```
@GET
    @Path("/getByTimeRange/{fromDate}/{toDate}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Measurements> getByTimeRange(@PathParam("fromDate") String fromDate, @PathParam("toDate") String toDate)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        MeasurementsService measurementsService = new MeasurementsService();
        List<Measurements> byTimeRange = null;
        try {
            byTimeRange = measurementsService.getByTimeRange(sdf.parse(fromDate), sdf.parse(toDate));
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MeasurementsJSONService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return byTimeRange;
    }
```

**Service Layer**

```
public List<Measurements> getByTimeRange(Date fromDate, Date toDate)
    {
        Session session = measurementsDAOInterface.openCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        List<Measurements> byTimeRange = null;

        try
        {
            transaction = measurementsDAOInterface.openTransaction(session);
            byTimeRange = measurementsDAOInterface.getByTimeRange(fromDate, toDate, session);
            transaction.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }

        return byTimeRange;
    }
```

**Database Layer**

```
public List<Measurements> getByTimeRange(Date fromDate, Date toDate, Session session) 
    {
        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Units where last_updated BETWEEN :fromDate and :toDate");
        query.setParameter("fromDate", fromDate);
        query.setParameter("toDate", toDate);
        List<Measurements> list = query.list();

        System.out.println("Size "+list.size() );
        System.out.println("Dates "+toDate +" : "+ fromDate);

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Item: "+list.get(i).getLastUpdated());
        }

        return list;
    }
```

So basically what I am trying to do is retrieving the data sets belong to a specific date range - Let's say between 14-02-2016 to 14-09-2016. In `Hibernate`, I have used the below code

```
FROM Units where last_updated BETWEEN :fromDate and :toDate
```

`Units` is the table and `last_updated` is the name of the column.

Anyway, I always get no results, just blank. Even the code `System.out.println("Size "+list.size() );` inside database layer prints `0`.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Can you put the Units class here? 
Have you a member in Units with last_updated name? 
Have you a data in the dataBase? 
If you run the normal SQL query in the database it has any results?

Here I give you an example of a Between with dates.

```
@Override
public List<Auto> getAutosFechaVenta(Calendar fechaDesde, Calendar fechaHasta) {

    EntityManager em = null;
    List<Auto> listaAutos = null;

    try {
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        String autosFechabetween = "from Auto a where fechaVenta between :desde and :hasta ";
        Query query = em.createQuery(autosFechabetween);
        query.setParameter("desde", fechaDesde);
        query.setParameter("hasta", fechaHasta);

        listaAutos = query.getResultList();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
    return listaAutos;
}
```

When you start the transaction? See my code:
em.getTransaction().begin();

Maybe you can try with query.getResultList();

I hope this example can hel you. Let my know your results.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. ''ast_updated' is the column name. In 'Units' class it is 'lastUpdated'. Anyway I'm all lf my former queries I used these column names.

Comment: I think I found the case. I am calling to the wrong table! But let me check.

Comment: Yeah, that is the issue. Incorrect table name. Thank you a lot for offering me support. I found the error when you specifically asked about `last_updated` in `Units` table. +1 from me.

Comment: very happy of help you and you found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I have used an incorrect table name in my query. It should be `FROM Measurements where last_updated BETWEEN :fromDate and :toDate`